Trying to migrate 1st gen to 2nd gen firebase functions, While deploying with "firebase deploy" commands, Cloud Run service `testV2` does not exist
My initial functions list

test            ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger   us-central1  1st gen
upload          ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger   us-central1  1st gen

Migrating test(1st gen) into testV2 (2nd gen) without deleting the 1st gen function because of donwtime. Now my functions list like, test (1st gen) function no longer needed now

test            ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger   us-central1  1st gen
testV2          ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger   us-central1  2nd gen
upload          ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger   us-central1  1st gen

After testV2(2nd gen) function running successfully. Planning to delete test (1st gen). Now i am running firebase deploy
The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
test(us-central1)
If you are renaming a function or changing its region, it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one to prevent event loss. For more info, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify
? Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployments. Yes
functions: deleting Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function test(us-central1)...
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Cloud Run service testV2 does not exist in region us-central1 in this project.
why it's saying Cloud Run service testV2 does not exist, even it's running?

If you're getting an error message from the Firebase CLI that's confusing and doesn't suggest a clear action to take, you should reach out to Firebase support directly for assistance.
